# Linux complains a shared library doesn't exist when it really does

Tags: c, linux, alsa

I'm trying to develop a plugin for alsa.  I compiled my plugin as a shared library and copies it to

```
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/alsa-lib/libasound_module_pcm_myplug.so
```

Then I try to test it using arecord and get the following error

```
arecord --device=my_plug_test blah.pcm
ALSA lib dlmisc.c:254:(snd1_dlobj_cache_get) Cannot open shared library /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/alsa-lib/libasound_module_pcm_myplug.so
arecord: main:682: audio open error: No such device or address
```

But the file does clearly exist.  I'm wondering if there is something about using .so files that i'm overlooking. Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: This is just a guess: check that the .so is read-only and owned by root.

Answer (score 3):

Could be some other dependency not found. Try:

```
ldd /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/alsa-lib/libasound_module_pcm_myplug.so
```

Or, is it possible your system is expecting 32-bit but you compiled 64-bit or vice versa?

Check with:`uname -a`